# Is there a closed expression for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^2a^n}{n!}$, where $a \in (0,\infty)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, closed-form

Is there a closed expression for $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^2a^n}{n!}$, where $a \in (0,\infty)$?

I have concluded that the sum converges using the ratio test:

$\displaystyle\frac{(n+1)^2a^{n+1} n!}{n^2a^n(n+1)!}=\frac{(n+1)a}{n^2} \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Also, by comparison the following "similar expression" has a closed form:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{na^n}{n!} = a\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{na^{n-1}}{n!}=ae^a$$

Comment: Good start. Now, can you find a closed form for $\sum_{n \geq 0}{\frac{n(n-1)a^n}{n!}}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
Differentiate both sides:
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}$$
Multiply by $x$:
$$xe^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{nx^n}{n!}$$
Differentiate both sides:
$$(x+1)e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^2x^{n-1}}{n!}$$
Multiply by $x$:
$$x(x+1)e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^2x^n}{n!}$$

Answer (score 5):

Hint. Note that for $n\geq 2$,
$$\frac{n^2}{n!}=\frac{n(n-1)+n}{n!}=\frac{1}{(n-2)!}+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Another approach:**

> Consider Poisson distribution:
> $$P(X=n)=\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda}$$

For Poisson distribution, we know:
$$Var(X)=E(X)=\lambda$$
and

$$Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$$
then we get,

$$E(X^2)=\lambda+\lambda^2$$

Therefore,

$$\lambda+\lambda^2=E(X^2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda}$$

Finally, multiply $e^\lambda$ on both sides,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}=e^{\lambda}(\lambda+\lambda^2)$$